# Undefined Name Caesar Cypher

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was making an exercise about Caesar's Cypher and I all went well when I made it "plain code" but when I tried to make it a function I kept getting the same error when I tried to used it in the Python Shell.

Can someone explain me why is it happening or what should I change to make it work?

Thank you in advance

The "plain" code was:

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

character = input("Please a character:")
displacement = int(input("Please enter a number:"))

position = alphabet.find(character)
newPosition = (position + displacement) % 26
newCharacter = alphabet[newPosition]

print(newCharacter)
```

My function was:

```
def cesar(character, displacement):
    """
    Receives a certain letter and a certain displacement size and codifies 
    that letter by giving it that displacement
    Requires: a letter from the alphabet with no variations (e.g:á,ê,õ) and 
    displacement > 0
    Ensures: a codified letter
    """
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    position = alphabet.find(character)
    newPosition = (alphabet + displacement)%26
    newCharacter = alphabet[newPosition]
    return newCharacter
```

But when I use e.g:

```
cesar(a,5)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
cesar(a,5)
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: Here `a` is an identifier, not a string, it should probably be `cesar('a', 5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [8]: def cesar(character, displacement):
   ...:     """
   ...:     Receives a certain letter and a certain displacement size and codifies 
   ...:     that letter by giving it that displacement
   ...:     Requires: a letter from the alphabet with no variations (e.g:á,ê,õ) and 
   ...:     displacement > 0
   ...:     Ensures: a codified letter
   ...:     """
   ...:     alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
   ...: 
   ...:     position = alphabet.find(character)
   ...:     newPosition = (position + displacement)%26
   ...:     newCharacter = alphabet[newPosition]
   ...:     return newCharacter
```

Do like this and then call:

`cesar('a',5)`

Comment: replace `alphabet` by `position` in your function `cesar`

Comment: Actually your code is correct in `plain code` you type wrong in your `function`.

Comment: Thank you, it works but is there a way for the return not to contain quotation marks?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Say Technically with example.

Comment: When I use `cesar('a',5)` the output in the shell will be `'f'` but I want it just to be `f`. How can I do that?

Comment: How it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: `cesar('a',5)`

Longer answer: When you say `cesar(a,5)`, Python thinks that `a` is a programming type e.g. a variable while when you say `'a'` this is then counted as a data type called a character. If you want to know more about data types check this out: https://realpython.com/python-data-types/